# How do I output matching data from two URLs in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api, coinbase-api

I'm fetching data from two links, a list of coins, and a list of events. The data gets rendered in the render section.

```
componentDidMount() {
Promise.all([
  fetch('https://coindar.org/api/v2/coins?access_token=36174:fy7i3eWjxllsdwhl80c'),
  fetch('https://coindar.org/api/v2/events?access_token=36174:fy7i3eWjxllsdwhl80c&page=1&page_size=30&filter_date_start=2018-10-01&filter_date_end=2020-07-01&sort_by=views&order_by=1')])
    .then(([res1, res2]) => Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json()]))
    .then(([data1, data2]) => this.setState({
      events: data2, 
      coins: data1,
      coinid: [],
      isLoaded: true,
    }));
}

 render() {
var {isLoaded, events, coins,coinid} = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ul>
    {events.map(events => (
      <li key={events.id} value={events.coin_id} > Name: {events.caption} Coin id: {events.coin_id} <!-- Image here.. coins.image_32 --> </li>))}
    </ul>
    <ul>
    {coins.map(coins => (
      <li key={coins.id}> Name: {coins.name} : Coin id: {coins.id}</li>))}
    </ul>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

The URLs can be copy pasted to see the data, what I'm trying to achieve is a list of events (second URL) with their images and coin name (first URL). In other languages the first step could be to use a `where` clause (`where events.coin_id == coins.id`) however, I'm not sure how to go about it with React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like nothing related to react, it's pure javascript implementation is enough to achieve our desire functionality.

just introduce 2 more state properties like `matchEvents` and `matchCoins`, apply ***where clause (where events.coin_id == coins.id)***

I'm not sure you need to 2 filters here, just modify based on your needs.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
        fetch('https://coindar.org/api/v2/coins?access_token=36174:fy7i3eWjxllsdwhl80c'),
        fetch('https://coindar.org/api/v2/events?access_token=36174:fy7i3eWjxllsdwhl80c&page=1&page_size=30&filter_date_start=2018-10-01&filter_date_end=2020-07-01&sort_by=views&order_by=1')])
        .then(([res1, res2]) => Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json()]))
        .then(([data1, data2]) => this.setState({
            events: data2,
            coins: data1,
            matchEvents: data2.filter(event => {
                return data1.some(coin => events.coin_id == coin.id)
            }),
            matchCoins: data1.filter(coin => {
                return data2.some(event => events.coin_id == coin.id)
            }),
            coinid: [],
            isLoaded: true,
        }));
}

render() {
    var { isLoaded, events, coins, coinid, matchEvents, matchCoins } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ul>
                {matchEvents.map(events => (
                    <li key={events.id} value={events.coin_id} > Name: {events.caption} Coin id: {events.coin_id} <!-- Image here.. coins.image_32 --> </li>))}
            </ul>
            <ul>
                {matchCoins.map(coins => (
                    <li key={coins.id}> Name: {coins.name} : Coin id: {coins.id}</li>))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I assume that I need to initialize 2 empty arrays in the contstructor (matchEvents and matchCoins) and set them in the render state (var  { isLoaded, events, coins, coini,matchCoins, matchEvents} = this.state;)

Comment: @MehdiElBouzidi that's right, just modified render(), we need to added in constructor as well.  As you mentioned.

Comment: Ah I got what I needed somewhat :), Ill try to figure the rest out myself, uve been of incredible help, thanks a lot :)